# Spring properties configuration using @PropertySource with external JSON file

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot with an access to keycloak. I need to leave the keycloak configuration in the keycloak.json file I would like to get teh values from the json using the PropertySource annotation...

My application.yml

```
keycloak:
   configurationFile: "classpath:keycloak.json"
```

My keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "MyRealm",
  "auth-server-url": "https://keycloakURL",
....
}
```

My class

```
@Controller
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:keycloak.json")
public class MyClass{

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@RequestMapping(value = "/mycontroller", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String method(Model model) {
    env.getProperty("auth-server-url")
}
```

The problem is that i am getting null for this environment variable

Comment: Run in debug, put a breakpoint on env.getProperty, then look at the property sources on env and see if you have anything in the source for keycloak.json as a starting point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load spring-boot properties from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564166/load-spring-boot-properties-from-json-file)

Comment: I have the environment variables in the application.yml which is classpath:keycloak.json  but not the content of keycloak.json file

Answer (score 0):

If env is null, maybe the issue is with the import.

> org.springframework.core.env.Environment

Else if the value queried from the environment is empty. In spring boot application, configuration of JSON file as property is quite different please refer the [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564166/load-spring-boot-properties-from-json-file),
[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277392/best-way-to-load-some-json-files-into-a-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 0):

I know using `@Value` is somewhat discouraged in favor of `env.getProperty()`, but I found the former much more reliable and straight forward. The proper way to use `@Value` from a `PropertySource` is described in [mkyong's great tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

> To resolve ${} in @Values, you must register a static
>   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in either XML or annotation
>   configuration file.

Comment: I have tried what you said about @value.
    @Value("${keycloak.configurationFile}")
    private String authServerUrl;
    Returns  "classpath:keycloak.json"
 
 
 @Value("${auth-server-url}")
 private String authServerUrl;
 Spring wont start..

Comment: @testeurFou It should be 
    `@PropertySource("classpath:keycloak.json") 
    public class MyClass{
        @Value("${auth-server-url}") 
         private String authServerUrl; 
    }`

Comment: @testeurFou also I don't know about `@Controller` and `@Configuration` in the same file. At the very least (and assuming it works) it is recommendable to keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for now but we have a ticket for it https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4942