# How to place @Bean factory method in the bean class itself?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a class that shall contain data which is de-serialized from a JSON file. This data shall be available in my application, so I want to bind it as bean.

To keep the de-serialization logic and and the data structure together, I wanted to put the `@Bean` annotated factory method into the data class itself – like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyData {

    // factory method
    @Bean
    public static MyData loadMyData(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream input = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:data.json").getInputStream()) {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, MyData.class);
        } 
    }

    // data structure
    private Map<String, DataDetail> details;

    // ...
}
```

However this fails because `@ComponentScan` finds two bean definitions now:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.example.MyData' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: myData,loadMyData

I also tried to replace the `@Configuration` with `@Component`, but the result is the same.

Am I just missing the right annotation on the class, or is it just not possible to place the `@Bean` method in the bean class itself?

Comment: take a look at [Best way to load some JSON files into a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34277392/217324)

Comment: do you need two beans of same type? you can name them unique and `Autowire` the corresponding one

Comment: No, I only want one bean. But so far I haven't figured out how to get this in the described scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i prefer layered architecture with spring boot, so with two different layers for `Configuration` and `model`, for example

package **app.config**

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataConfig {

// factory method
@Bean
public static MyData loadMyData(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream input = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:data.json").getInputStream()) {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, MyData.class);
    } 
 }

}
```

package **com.model**

```
public class MyData {

// data structure
private Map<String, DataDetail> details;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Deadpool answered, you should separate the `MyData` class from the `@Configurtion` class.
`@Configuration` is meta-annotated with `@Component` so once you annotate `MyData` with `@Configuration`, Spring also relate it as a regular bean, and that makes the double defenition of the `MyData` beans.